# platform dependent error with psycopg2: (only) Win10 says "can't pickle psycopg2.extensions.connection"

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, cross-platform, pickle, psycopg2

I have some multiprocessing code that connects to postgres. The core logic is not very complex:

```
manager = Manager()
managedwork = manager.list(thelist)
connections = {i: setconnection() for i in range(workercount)}
jobs = [Process(target=managedworker, args=(managedwork, connections[i])) for i in range(workercount)]
```

`setconnection()` returns an object that has a psycopg2 connection inside of it. The interface is not very interesting: `c = setconnection()` + `c.dbconnection` will give you just what you think you might get. After we have defined the jobs, the following generates the problem:

```
for j in jobs:
    j.start()
for j in jobs:
    j.join()
```

the `start()` throws an exception on Windows10 with python37: `TypeError: can't pickle psycopg2.extensions.connection objects`. The offended party is `ForkingPickler`.

This same code works just fine on macOS, FreeBSD, and Linux where `python37` is also installed. `psycopg 2.7.5` is also deployed on all four platforms.I would be curious to know what sorts of fixes might be needed to get past this problem. I'm not used to Windows at all, so maybe it is obvious to someone else why this happened.

Thanks for your attention and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question because it might help others...

On `posix` systems (`os.name`) there is a threading problem if the connection is **not** sent to each worker. On `nt` systems (`os.name` again) the connection cannot be pickled and so cannot be sent to the workers. The core issue seems to be the `spawn` method that `nt` requires - in contradistinction to the `posix` use of `fork` - for `multiprocessing`.

The core program now works via a somewhat ugly workaround. Send `None` as the connection if  `os.name` = `nt`. Then grab a connection inside the newly spawned copy of the interpreter by testing: `if not connection: connection = setconnection()`. Icky, but perhaps unavoidable since the implementation of `multiprocessing` is not uniform across platforms...